# Can an invertible function of a nonuniform random variable create a uniform random variable?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable that **does not** have a uniform distribution. Let $Y = r(X)$ where $r$ is an invertible function.

Is it possible for $Y$ to be uniform? If so, what is wrong with this line of argument that it cannot be:

Imagine the PDF for $X$ looks the picture below. Although X was stated to be continuous, the histogram here only has 3 possible values but that is just to make things more obvious -- I think the argument is the same for the continuous case -- just imagine infinitely more bars and the labels being the density instead of the count.

[image: f_X]

So 1 occurs 1/6 of the time, 2 occurs 2/6 of the time and 3 occurs 3/6 of the time. My argument is that any invertible function we pass X through can only shuffle the order of the bars, something like this:

[image]

Because $r$ must consistently send the same inputs to the same outputs, it must send the 1/6 chance occurrences of 1 consistently to some other number, 2 in this case. And it must consistently send the 3/6 chance occurrences of 3 to the same place everytime, 1 in this case. And because the function is invertible, it can't send distinct input values to the same output value.

Is my thinking correct?

Comment: "Although X was stated to be continuous, the histogram here only has 3 possible values but that is just to make things more obvious" This is the exact point where you go astray.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is a straightforward way to convert any continuous random variable to a uniform distribution. Simply apply its CDF. Then you have $$ P(F_X(X)\le x) = P(X\le F_X^{-1}(x)) = F_X(F_X^{-1}(x)) = x,$$ so $F_X(X)$ is uniformly distributed.

(Note as Ian mentions in the comments, though the above argument might seem to fail if the CDF is not strictly increasing, it goes through when we interpret $F^{-1}_X$ as the generalized inverse / quantile function. Atoms, however, still cause the argument to fail since $F(F^{-1}(x)) > x$ if $F^{-1}(x)$ is an atom.)

Your argument is very specific to discrete variables and doesn't allow for the fact that we can stretch and compress regions of the real line with a transformation. The closest analogy is you could put the discrete values with the largest frequencies far apart from everything and put the ones with lower frequency close together, smoothing out the distribution in a coarse grained sense.

Comment: Note that it is important that at least the CDF is continuous (it's not essential that the r.v. is continuous). The only way this can fail is if the r.v. has a discrete part, and in this case the property above will fail, even with $F^{-1}$ interpreted as the quantile function. (By the way, even in the continuous case, $F^{-1}$ must be interpreted as the quantile function, because $F$ may have flat regions and thus fail to be injective.)

Comment: @Ian I said continuous RV with strictly increasing CDF (though perhaps I should have emphasized that this was necessary).

Comment: I would not bother to postulate that the CDF is strictly increasing, because this is a very special case. Just use the quantile function instead of the inverse.

Comment: @Ian ah yeah, that's right, thanks. I always had 'continuous' mean CDF is continuous... not absolutely continuous / has PDF.

Comment: I accept your proof but still don't get the intuition. From a programmer standpoint it is as if we use a biased RNG to generate a number many times, each time plugging it into a function, and that function somehow doesn't end up returning the return values of the more frequent inputs more often than the rare ones, even though it can't pull any shenanigans like ignoring the input or always returning the same number since it is invertible. I'm having trouble seeing how that's possible.

Comment: @JosephGarvin It might be more intuitive to go the other direction from a uniform distribution to (say) an exponential. Let's say we have some kind of ideal uniform rng that returns some large but finite set of numbers between zero and one on an evenly spaced grid. We transform to an exponential via $u\mapsto -\ln(1-u).$ Then what comes out is uniformly distributed on a finite set of values, but the values are no longer evenly spaced, but rather stretched out so they cover a much wider range but become more and more thinly spread out at larger values. (cont'd)

Comment: @JosephGarvin The result approximates the exponential in the bulk of the distribution, but the discreteness effects will be pronounced in the far tail.

Comment: Now let's go the other way. If we had some kind of idealized exponential rng that gave samples on a uniform grid from $0$ to some decently large number, but with different frequencies to approximate an exponential distribution, and then we pass the result through $x\mapsto 1-e^{-x},$ then the infrequent large values will get compressed and appear just to the left of 1. They will occur less frequently, but they will be denser, so that the probability in a small interval will match that of the more frequently occuring, but less densely spaced values that map to the regions closer to zero.

Comment: @JosephGarvin From the point of view of discrete probability, you are correct that there is no way to use an injective function to change the probabilities of *individual values*. Once some $x_0$ has a given probability, $f(x_0)$ has the same probability as $x_0$, because the only way to see the value $f(x_0)$ is for the underlying RNG to pick the value $x_0$. However, you can push some values closer together and others further apart, which leads to more probability in certain *intervals* than others.